# Special Character preg_match

Tags: php, regex

The regex below is based off another stack answer... but my results are not the same. Special characters are not being checked.

lowercase, uppercase, number and a special character is needed.

**ex: qwertyu1wW** is processing without a special character

```
if (!preg_match('/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}/', $pass)) {
```

Comment: "Special character" is not a thing. Do you mean "punctuation"? If so, what punctuation characters in particular?

Comment: The regex is only looking for a lowercase letter `[a-z]`, an uppercase letter `[A-Z]`, and a number `\d` on a string that is at-least 8 characters long (`{8,}`). I'm not sure what the last `.` is there for, maybe trying to require a period be present as well?

Comment: @deceze punctuation/special character i guess they're one in the same. the term "special character" is used when referring to anything other than a number or letter for a password

Comment: And that's a terrible nomenclature. Different things are "special" in different circumstances or to different people. If you mean "punctuation character" say "punctuation character", if you mean "non-alphanumeric character" say "non-alphanumeric character".

Comment: @deceze I agree with you, not saying your wrong. it just seems to be common practice to write special character rather than non-alphanumeric character. It could be that special character is shorter to write and sounds less technical to a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For "anything other than a number or letter"

Use the following:

```
if (!preg_match('/(?=.*[\W_-])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}/', $pass)) {
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```